# scrollPosition in view aligned scrollTargetLayout does not work when custom views are inside ForEach

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Ok so I have noticed that on iOS 17.2 the scrollPosition modifier does not update with an HStack when using a "custom" view.

Here is the setup

```
struct NumberView: View {
    var number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)").frame(width: 150, height: 150).background(.red)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    struct identifiableNumber: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var id: Int {
            return number
        }
        let number: Int
    }
    
    @State var scrollID: Int?
    let allNumbers: [identifiableNumber] = [identifiableNumber(number: 0), identifiableNumber(number: 1), identifiableNumber(number: 2), identifiableNumber(number: 3), identifiableNumber(number: 4)]
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(scrollID ?? -1)")
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(allNumbers) { numberIn in
                    NumberView(number: numberIn.number).scrollTargetLayout()
                }
            }.frame(height: 100).scrollTargetLayout()
        }.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned(limitBehavior: .always))
            .defaultScrollAnchor(.leading)
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollID)
    }
}
```

In this case scrollID will not update when the view is scrolled. There are two ways to "fix" this however. One is to use `LazyHStack` instead of `HStack` and the second is to use a non "custom" view like so

```
Text("\(numberIn.number)").frame(width: 150, height: 150).background(.red)
```

Either of these will make scrollID update again.

The problem is for my actual use case I can't use either of these options. I cannot use a LazyHStack nor can I use a non custom type... Do I have any options that could make this work? How do you file SwiftUI bugs?

Comment: This works in iOS 17.0, so I think it is just a bug. You can file bugs using the [Feedback Assistant app](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: Same issue here. I don’t want to use Lazy-container for some reasons and I need to split the code out to make it reusable.